# I get undefined property when I share boolean data between Angular components using @ViewChild

Tags: html, angular, typescript, angular-components, angular-template

I have a component named `RedirectUserToMobileAppComponent` , I want to share a boolean property from it named `enableLoginForm` with `app.component`.
When I execute, I get this error :

> **enableLoginForm** is undefined property on **ngAfterViewInit** in **app.component**

this is `RedirectUserToMobileAppComponent` component:

```
    import {
        Component,
        ComponentFactoryResolver,
        ComponentRef,
        Inject,
        Input,
        OnInit,
        Output,
        ViewChild,
        ViewContainerRef,
    } from '@angular/core';
    import { Observable, Subscription } from 'rxjs';
    import { filter, map, pluck, tap } from 'rxjs/operators';
    import { ActivatedRoute, Router } from '@angular/router';
    import { MAT_DIALOG_SCROLL_STRATEGY_FACTORY } from '@angular/material/dialog';

    @Component({
        selector: 'redirect-user-to-mobile-app',
        templateUrl: './redirect-user-to-mobile-app.component.html',
        styleUrls: ['./redirect-user-to-mobile-app.component.sass'],
    })
    export class RedirectUserToMobileAppComponent implements OnInit {
        constructor(
        ) {}
        enableLoginForm = false;
        ngOnInit(): void {}
    
        OnLogin(): void {
            this.enableLoginForm = true;
            this.router.navigate(['../login']);
        }
        
    }
```

and this is `app.component`:

```
    import {
    Component,
    HostListener,
    OnDestroy,
    OnInit,
    ViewChild,
    AfterViewInit,
} from '@angular/core';
import { MatIconRegistry } from '@angular/material/icon';
import { DomSanitizer } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { FirebaseService } from './services/firebase/firebase.service';
import {
    SnakeMessage,
    SnakeMessageService,
} from './services/snakeMessage/snakeMessage.service';
import { MatSnackBar } from '@angular/material/snack-bar';
import { Subscription } from 'rxjs';
import { StorageService } from './services/storage/storage.service';
import { AuthService } from './services/auth/auth.service';
import { RedirectUserToMobileAppComponent } from './redirect-user-to-mobile-app/redirect-user-to-mobile-app.component';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-component',
    templateUrl: './app.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss'],
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy, AfterViewInit {
    favIcon: HTMLLinkElement = document.querySelector('#appIcon');
    private snakeMessageSub: Subscription;
    isLoading = true;
    isLogged: boolean;

    @ViewChild(RedirectUserToMobileAppComponent)
    redirectComponent!: RedirectUserToMobileAppComponent;

    constructor(
        private matIconRegistry: MatIconRegistry,
        private firebaseService: FirebaseService,
        private snakeMessageService: SnakeMessageService,
        private _snackBar: MatSnackBar,
        private storageService: StorageService,
        private domSanitizer: DomSanitizer,
        private authService: AuthService
    ) {
        this.registerCustomIcons();
        this.storageService.initDB();
        this.storageService.onLoaded$.subscribe((loaded) => {
            if (loaded) {
                this.isLoading = false;
            }
        });
        this.isLogged = this.authService.isLoggedIn;
    }

    ngAfterViewInit() {
        if (this.redirectComponent.enableLoginForm) {
            this._is = this.redirectComponent.enableLoginForm;
        }
    }

    ngOnInit(): void {
        this.snakeMessageSub = this.snakeMessageService.messageSub.subscribe(
            (snakeMessage: SnakeMessage) => {
                this._snackBar.open(snakeMessage.message, snakeMessage.action, {
                    duration: 3000,
                    horizontalPosition: 'center',
                    verticalPosition: 'top',
                });
            }
        );
    }
```

this is my app.component.html

```
<ng-container *ngIf="!isLoading">
<ng-container *ngIf="isMobileDevice() && !isLogged">
    <redirect-user-to-mobile-app> </redirect-user-to-mobile-app>
    <router-outlet
        *ngIf="enableLoginForm"
    ></router-outlet>
</ng-container>

<router-outlet *ngIf="!isMobileDevice()"></router-outlet>
```

Comment: I would suggest including some of the HTML excerpt of the App component that uses the child component to help resolve this question.

Comment: It's done , thank you .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have changed the method, I have used @Output() component and it works fine:

this is `RedirectUserToMobileAppComponent` component after changing the method :

```
    import {
    Component,
    ComponentFactoryResolver,
    ComponentRef,
    Inject,
    Input,
    OnChanges,
    OnInit,
    Output,
    SimpleChanges,
    ViewChild,
    ViewContainerRef,
    EventEmitter,
} from '@angular/core';
import { Observable, Subscription } from 'rxjs';
import { filter, map, pluck, tap } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { ActivatedRoute, Router } from '@angular/router';
import { MAT_DIALOG_SCROLL_STRATEGY_FACTORY } from '@angular/material/dialog';
@Component({
    selector: 'yobi-redirect-user-to-mobile-app',
    templateUrl: './redirect-user-to-mobile-app.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./redirect-user-to-mobile-app.component.sass'],
})
export class RedirectUserToMobileAppComponent implements OnInit {
    constructor(
        private router: Router,
        private componentFactoryResolver: ComponentFactoryResolver
    ) {}

    @Output() _enableLoginForm: EventEmitter<boolean> = new EventEmitter();
    variable: any;
    login: boolean;
    enableLoginForm = false;
    enableSignupForm = false;
    ngOnInit(): void {}

    sendDataToParent() {
        this.enableLoginForm = true;
        this._enableLoginForm.emit(this.enableLoginForm);
        console.log(this.enableLoginForm + ' From redirect ');
    }
```

I added this to `RedirectUserToMobileAppComponent.html`:

```
<a class="login-text" (click)="sendDataToParent()">
          Login
      </a>
```

I added this code to `app.component` :

```
receiveChildData($event) {
    this.enableLoginForm = $event;
}
```

I added this code to the app.component.html :

```
<redirect-user-to-mobile-app
        (_enableLoginForm)="receiveChildData($event)"
    >
    </redirect-user-to-mobile-app>
```

Answer (score 3):

This is how you use ViewChild:

```
@ViewChild('templateId', { static: false }) redirectComponent: RedirectUserToMobileAppComponent;
```

You should have the templateId set in the template part :

```html
<redirect-user-to-mobile-app #templateId> ... </redirect-user-to-mobile-app>
```

EDIT: Though I agree with skyBlue, you should use a service to shared data between components

Comment: When I used this @ViewChild('templateId', { static: false }) redirectComponent: RedirectUserToMobileAppComponent I got this Error : (!The same error ),core.js:4197 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'enableLoginForm')

Comment: Ok sorry then buddy, did you add the #templateId in the html template ?

Answer (score 1):

`ViewChild` returns a **reference to the HTML element**.

I will quote from [angular.io](https://angular.io/api/core/ViewChild):

> Property decorator that configures a view query. The change detector looks for the first element or the directive matching the selector in the view DOM. If the view DOM changes, and a new child matches the selector, the property is updated.

So you cant access it's controller variables with `ViewChild`.

My suggestion for you is to use a `service` for passing data.

Comment: thank you a lot , I will try to create a service, I will tell you if there is any news :)

Comment: did you succeed? @Wahéb

Comment: I have changed the method, I have used @Output() decorator and it works fine

Comment: I posted the answer bellow